# Variation of parameters for 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters describes the general solution to a second order system under "General Second Order Equation."  What does it mean when the forcing function $f$ is not $C^1$?  Does that just mean that the assumption of the form of the particular solution is wrong? (We know from general theory that there exists a unique solution per initial condition on $u$ and its first derivative.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @MikePierce : How is it no longer relevant?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Because it stemmed from a misunderstanding caused by a typo on Wikipedia that is no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the article was edited meanwhile, but I do not see any smoothness assumption on $f$ there. To obtain a solution of $u''+p(x)u'+q(x)u = f(x)$, we integrate $f$ against some kernel depending on $p,q$ and boundary conditions.  This works   even if $f$ is merely an $L^1$ function.